# submit a form with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

i have a html page, which contains a form and i want when the form is successfully submited, show the below div:

```
<div class="response" style="display: none;">
  <p>you can download it<a href="{{ link }}">here</a></p>
</div>
```

i also have a jquery function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#sendButton').click(function(e) {            
                e.preventDefault();
                var temp = $("#backupSubmit").serialize();
                validateForm();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: temp,
                    url: 'backup/',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(".response").show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

</script>
```

and in my `views.py` (code behind) i create a link and pass it to html page. i have:

```
def backup(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method=='POST':
            //create a link that user can download a file from it. (link)
            variables = RequestContext(request,{'link':link})
            return render_to_response('backup.html',variables)
        else:
            return render_to_response('backup.html')
    else:
        return render_to_response("show.html", {
            'str': "bad Request! :(",
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
backup = login_required(backup)
```

my problem: it seems that my view doesn't execute. it doesn't show me the link that i send to this page. it seems that only jQuery function is executed. i'm confused. how can i make both of them to execute(i mean jQuery function and then the url i set in this function which make my view to be executed.)

i don't know how to use serialize function. whenever i searched, they wrote that:

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation and produces query string like "a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5.

i don't know when i have to use it, while i can access to my form field in request.Post["field name"]. and i don't know what should be the data which is in success: function(data) in my situation.

thank very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get and display the `data` from your ajax post function, where `data` is the response you render through your DJango server, for example:

```
t = Template("{{ link }}")
c = Context({"link": link})
t.render(c):
```

Your JS / jQuery should become something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#sendButton').click(function(e) {            
            e.preventDefault();
            var temp = $("#backupSubmit").serialize();
            validateForm();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: temp,
                url: 'backup/',

                success: function(data) {
                    // 'data' is the response from your server
                    // (=the link you want to generate from the server)

                    // Append the resulting link 'data' to your DIV '.response'
                    $(".response").html('<p>you can download it<a href="'+data+'">here</a></p>');

                    $(".response").show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wait mate.. I'm a bit confused with your answer... XD The thing is: when you submit you click your `sendButton`, you receive ajax request in views.py, through your function. So, in this function, you'll have to generate your link and render it (without template: just "print" the link). Once it is rendered, this rendered information (=your link) is sent as `data` (the variable in your success function). You then add this new generated link to your DIV then it's ok. I'm not sure if I was clear :S... Tell me if I'm wrong or if it's not what you really want.

Comment: thanks a lot. as you told data is the response from server, which i receive from views.py. what do you mean by "t = Template("{{ link }}")
c = Context({"link": link})
t.render(c):"? i send link data to my html page via render_to_response, my question is i don't know where to receive it in html page? can you please tell me where exactly i can create data(use link)in html. if data should be "link data" received from views, so what is "data: temp"? why should i use "data: temp"? is always necessary to use serialize? sorry it's the first time i'm using this function :"> thank you for your help:)

Comment: aha, you mean that whenever i pass a dictionary to my template(html file), (which is link in my example ), the parameter "data" automatically contains link, if i send to dictionary(link and s.th else), "data" contains both?

Comment: Normally `data` contains automatically  the answer that is "printed" by the server. So, it can only be a a string.

Comment: I think you just simply need to render / "print" your link, in your django function which is supposed to answer to the ajax request.